# d3 Updating Subcircle Data Zoomable Pack Layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, circle-pack

After reading several tutorials, I have still some difficulties seeing on how to navigate between DOM and data in d3. 
For the following example, I would like to add the circle only to the selected circle:

http://jsfiddle.net/stefanf/6Qm2z/13/'obj = {
                  "name": "Q",
                  "size": 1
         }

```
    // how could I add it only to the selected element?
     node.children.push(obj)
     refreshGraph()'
```

however not sure, how I could navigate from d3.select(".selected") to its data...?

Comment: You can get the data for a selection with `.data()`, e.g. `d3.select(".selected").data()`.

Comment: Thank you. But still not getting it to work with (the new circle appears, but the behaviour is strange :/):   `var selected = d3.select(".selected").data();`  `selected[0].children.push(obj);`

Comment: Well what are you trying to do?

Comment: Selecting a circle by mouse click, clicking add -> the circle should be placed inside the selected circle.

Comment: You're currently only modifying the data, you also have to then redraw everything based on the new data.

Comment: this is what I am trying to do with refreshGraph()..

Comment: Works for me -- http://jsfiddle.net/6Qm2z/17/

Comment: Something is still buggy, by selecting D and click add, D will become a new circle without children..

Comment: Use a key function to `.data()` for that -- http://jsfiddle.net/6Qm2z/22/

Comment: I see no difference in your jsfiddle?!

Comment: Line 53. I've added a key function to `.data()`.

Comment: Adding Circles works fine, but the text is still not displayed correctly / it changes by adding several circles. Do I have to use update()-Method in the refreshGraph() method?

Comment: Well the first step would be to handle update and exit selections in addition to enter: http://jsfiddle.net/6Qm2z/23/ The other problem is that you're always adding the same data.